# Why does this DateTime function crashes my app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function to find the last available date in case 'today' (DateTime.now()) is already taken. However, wherever I put this function in my app, it will crash it:

```dart
DateTime findLastAvailableDate(List<DateTime> usedDates, DateTime currentDate) {
      DateTime lastAvailableDate = DateTime(currentDate.year,currentDate.month,currentDate.day);
  while (usedDates.contains(lastAvailableDate)) { 
        lastAvailableDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
   }   
   return lastAvailableDate;
}
```

the basic idea is to find the closest day from DateTime.now() that is available, i.e

````
DateTime lastAvailableDate = findLastAvailableDate(usedDates, DateTime.now());


lastAvailableDate would return 2021-08-10 in this case.

I'm not getting any stacktrace errors, the terminal just freezes, if I try to restart or hot reload I get this message :

```[  +25 ms] Reassembling application
   [+2004 ms] This is taking a long time; will now check for paused       isolates.
   [  +27 ms] Found 0 newly paused isolate(s).
````

Comment: Include the stacktrace.

Comment: How does it crash? Is there an error message? Also, your approach seems pretty inefficient; why not just sort the list of dates and pick the latest one on or before the current date?

Comment: I need to pick a date that has not been used yet.

Comment: You go into an infinite loop because `lastAvailableDate.subtract` does not mutate `lastAvailableDate`, and you ignore the newly returned `DateTime`.

Comment: My app is a weight tracking app, the user add the weight and the date they weighted themselves, if I follow your solution the users would be able to add dates in the future. This function is only used if the users has already added a date in the current day.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier sorting suggestion wasn't quite thought-out.  You can sort the list of used dates, iterate over them from newest to oldest, and return when you find non-consecutive dates.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do with this function! Thanks, I changed the while loop to : while (usedDates.contains(lastAvailableDate)) { 
        lastAvailableDate = lastAvailableDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
   } , now it works!